# DATERANGE index not used when lookup is done by range_contains_elem function

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jooq

I have followed https://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/07/postgresqls-best-kept-secret-and-how-to-use-it-with-jooq/#comment-147330 to support Postgres range type in Jooq. I have table like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE currency_conversion_rate_seq START 1;

CREATE TABLE currency_conversion_rate
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('currency_conversion_rate_seq'),
  rate numeric(15,8) NOT NULL,
  valid_range DATERANGE NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX currency_conversion_rate_valid_range_idx ON currency_conversion_rate 
USING GIST (valid_range);
```

When I use query as mentioned in blogpost, index is not used:

```
select * from currency_conversion_rate 
where range_contains_elem(valid_range, '1999-01-10'::date)
```

When I rewrite query, index is used:

```
select * from currency_conversion_rate where valid_range @> '1999-01-10'::date
```

Why? I use Postgres 9.5.

Comment: The [default GiST ops for range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING) mentions that the `=, &&, <@, @>, <<, >>, -|-, &<, and &>` **operators** are supported (note that there is no function here). Nonetheless `range_contains_elem()` does not seem to be a [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) function for range types. It *might* be a backing function for a range operator, but you shouldn't depend on that. Its name is subject to change without any prior notice.

Comment: Some indexes *can* use function call expressions, but this is rather [rare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html#AEN181436) in PostgreSQL. The [operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html) / [operator family](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopfamily.html) architecture is build around operators (hence the name). For comparison, developers tend to use `a_int = b_int` instead of `int4eq(a_int, b_int)` (despite the fact that its name `int4eq` is very unlikely to chage).